# WP E-Commerce Plugin With Membership

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I would like to add recurring monthly membership fees to the WP E-Commerce plugin. Also I would like this plugin to give away a free gift/product on sign up with 10% off existing products. This one time sign up feature would also need to allow for a (one time?) free shipping on all products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S2Member is a great plugin for membership. It will let you do things like Platinum, Gold and Silver membership levels even. You will need to create a custom function in order to give a free product on sign up, but that should be some fairly basic PHP work. eShop is probably the best plugin for ecommerce I know of. The answer really is that you will need a couple plugins plus some custom coding to get it working the way you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this question is extremely general and a bit inappropriate for this section, but I'd suggest looking at various WP E-Commerce plugins that you can customize to get the functionality you need.

Try taking a look at [this one](http://getshopped.org/), for example.

Comment: I'm talking about that plugin. I was referring to the functionality of it.

Comment: Ah, I believe you can use the 'membership' plugin to get that functionality.  Take a look at this thread: http://getshopped.org/forums/topic/recurring-payment-monthly-fee/